# Как подобное верстают адаптивно в Bootstrap 3?

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap

Как подобное сверсать по сетке Bootstrap что-бы было еще и под мобилу ?
Как это сделали бы вы - для себя ?

Я совсем салага и у меня на уме:
На больших экранах - разбить на 3 колонки:

1. 2 текста
2. 1 текст и картинка
3. 2 текста

Затем , картинку для больших экранов сделать со стрелками и текст подгонять под них. А на маленьких экранах картинка будет без стрелок и под всем текстом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разве на это возможен хотя бы приблизительно точный ответ? Не слишком подходящий сайт для такого вопроса. А по делу - при таких надобностях нанимается дизайнер, и верстается то, что он нарисует...

Comment: @vordzer я думал тут можно получить ответ на любой вопрос связанный с версткой и веб-программированием.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask на любой, с учётом правил и просьб